# How to print a div content with colors with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am trying to print a single div with a red color paragraph.

On screen, the div color appears  ok, with the paragraph in red color.

When I click on the button to print, the printer dialog show the page, but no color and  if I  click to send the preview to printer, the text is printed without color as well.

I have the printer configured to BW, but before print I change it to color mode.
The page is allways printed at BW.

What am I doing wrong?

//controller

```
$scope.PrintDoc=function(id) {
        var printSection = document.getElementById('printSection');
        // if there is no printing section, create one
        if (!printSection) {
            printSection = document.createElement('div');
            printSection.id = 'printSection';
            document.body.appendChild(printSection);
        }
        var elemToPrint = document.getElementById(id);
        if (elemToPrint) {
                    printElement(elemToPrint);
        }
        function printElement(elem) {
            // clones the element you want to print
            var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
            printSection.innerHTML = '';
            printSection.appendChild(domClone);
            window.print();
        }
}
```

//markup

```
<div id="folha">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 row-print">
            <div class="pull-left"><p>MY TEST</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" >
 <button type="button" ng-click="PrintDoc('folha')"
   class="btn btn-primary">
    Print
  </button>
</div>
```

//css

```
<style type="text/css">
@media screen {
    #folha {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media print {
body * {
    display:none;
}
.row-print{
  margin:15px; 
  color:red;
}
@page { margin:0cm }
    @page :first {
      margin-top:0cm;
    }
    @page :left {
      margin-left:0cm;
      margin-right:0cm;
    }
    @page :right {
      margin-left:0cm;
      margin-right:0cm;
    }

#printSection, #printSection * {
    display: block!important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}

#printSection {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
}

 </style>
```

Comment: If you are using Chrome, on the preview part there is an option to select Color or Black & White..  This is separate to the printer's property for Color & BW.

Comment: don't use javascript for this, you can create a stylesheet that is only used for printed content. google css media types.

Comment: HI, I am already using css with media print. I posted it.

Comment: @Keith Yes, I know. When I click print the printer dialog apperas. After that I select colored mode, no BW. But, the page allways print in BW. The dialog print preview also is BW.

Comment: May be a silly question, but will it print any web pages in colour?

Comment: @Archer  Yes, if use print menu of chrome to print this current page, the dialog printer preview shows colored and final print as well

Comment: When it shows the preview, you change it to colour and then print it - does it show the preview in colour at that point?

Comment: @Archer  No, it doesn´t

Comment: I can't help then - I just tested it and it works fine for me.  Does this do the same thing? https://jsfiddle.net/1q1srva0/

Comment: @Archer this is ok. The  dialog is in colour. But what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I will make a fiddle

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help - I just used your code and it works for me.  It printed red text.

Comment: Hi, thank you. The problem is with boostrap css overriding my css style.Any suggestion, please.

Comment: You need to edit the question and create a [MCVE]

Comment: @LuizAlves you never mentioned bootstrap in your OP. Try to be more specific in your CSS definition to ensure it is not over written by other sources or make sure it's the final CSS to load.